# NodeJs/Express - access view engines registered to app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm writing a middleware function at the moment and need a way to check the view engines that have been registered to the current app.

As it is possible in express to have two view engines:

```
app.engine('pug',...);
app.engine('jade',...);

app.set('view engine','pug');
app.set('view engine','jade');
//To send view
res.render('index.pug',{viewData:{}});
res.render('index.jade',{viewData:{}});
```

I need a way to determine the extensions of all current view engines.
However, upon checking app.get('view engine') or app.settings['view engine'] it is simply set to a string (with the value of the last call the set), rather than an array as I would have expected.

How can I get the information I need?

Answer (score 1):

`view engine` is defined as "The default engine extension to use when omitted". Therefore, you can only have one view engine at a time. Calls of `app.set('view engine', ...)` overwrite the default.

To get all *available* engines (set up with calls to `app.engine`), you can use the `engines` property. For instance,

```
console.log(Object.keys(app.engines));
// output: [ '.pug', '.jade' ]
```

However, that property is not part of [the API](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html), so it may break in future express.js versions.